# How to use nodeos command when deploying via Docker?

Tags: cleos, nodeos

I am able to run `cleos` from my command line after following [basic setup instructions](https://eosio-nodeos.readme.io/docs/docker-quickstart) to launch a private testnet, including setting an alias:

`alias cleos='docker exec -it eosio /opt/eosio/bin/cleos -u http://localhost:8888'`

However, how do I run the `nodeos` command so that I can follow along the [tutorial](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/docs/introduction-to-smart-contracts)? I cannot find the instructions for the `nodeos` setup or `alias` command.

Comment: you ran the `nodeos` command when you started your docker container  in the first step

Comment: @confused00, then how do I next run the command `nodeos -e -p eosio --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin --plugin eosio::history_api_plugin`? Thank you

Comment: that part assumes you installed `nodeos` locally and you don't have a node running already. if you're using docker, you can just continue using the docker command from the first link, or you don't need to run anything if you still have the node running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you followed the second step you have started nodeos  if you have not follow the given command.

```
docker run --rm --name eosio -d -p 8888:8888 -p 9876:9876 -v /tmp/work:/work -v /tmp/eosio/data:/mnt/dev/data -v /tmp/eosio/config:/mnt/dev/config eosio/eos-dev  /bin/bash -c "nodeos -e -p eosio --plugin eosio::producer_plugin --plugin eosio::history_plugin --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin --plugin eosio::history_api_plugin --plugin eosio::http_plugin -d /mnt/dev/data --config-dir /mnt/dev/config --http-server-address=0.0.0.0:8888 --access-control-allow-origin=* --contracts-console --http-validate-host=false"
```

If you want to check just run

```
docker logs --tail 10 eosio
```

it will show the produced block list to you.